# Jackson custom xml deserialization

Tags: xml, xml-deserialization, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm having some problems trying to deserialize an xml into java pojo using jackson-dataformat-xml.

The xml looks like this:

```
<root>
    <arg>
        <id type="String" value="jd">USERNAME</id>
    </arg>
    <arg>
        <id type="String" value="John">NAME</id>
    </arg>
    <arg>
        <id type="String" value="Dafoe">SURNAME</id>
    </arg>
    <arg>
        <id type="String" value="16-04-1989">BIRTHDAY</id>
    </arg>
</root>
```

My pojo is the following:

```
public class User {

    String username;
    String name;
    String surname;
    String birthday;

}
```

Unfortunately i don't have the possibility to change the input xml format.
What is the correct approach to do this deserialization using this library?
I've already tried to solve this task with jackson's annotations but without success.